# Commit object on Vue X (via Actions)... possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've a question about Vue X and actions (with commit).

It's possible to input object in Commit ?

Same as :

```
...
action{
  ResetLoginStats({commit}){
    commit({
      'SetMutation1':false,
      'SetMutation2':true,
      'SetMutation3':''
      ...
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

All the part of Action :

```
ResetSignInStats({ commit }) {
            document.getElementById('Semail').value = '';
            document.getElementById('Spwd').value = '';
            document.getElementById('SpwdC').value = '';
            document.getElementById('Sname').value = '';
            document.getElementById('SBio').value = '';

            commit('setsubFailure', false);
            commit('setMSGfaillure','');
            commit('setsubOkay', false);
            commit('setsubCompleted', false);
            commit('setCHKeMail', false);
            commit('setCHKpassword', false);
            commit('setCHKuserName', false);
            commit('setLoading', false);
        },
```

Thank you for help & return.
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i use this way :

```
...
mutations:{
    setStats(state, newValue){
        state.status.setStatus = newValue.setStatus;
        ...
    }
}
...
actions:{
    ...
    ResetSignInStats({ commit }) {
        document.getElementById('Semail').value = '';
        document.getElementById('Spwd').value = '';
        document.getElementById('SpwdC').value = '';
        document.getElementById('Sname').value = '';
        document.getElementById('SBio').value = '';

        commit('setStats',{
            setStatus : flase,
            setMSGfaillure : '',
            setsubOkay : false,
            setsubCompleted: false,
            setCHKeMail : false,
            setCHKpassword : false,
            setCHKuserName : false,
            setLoading : false
        });
    },
}
...
```

Thank's for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it like this

```
...
action{
  ResetLoginStats({commit}){
    commit('SetMutation1', false);
    commit('SetMutation2', true);
    commit('SetMutation3', '');
  }
  ...
}
```

Details here
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload

Comment: Hello, thank you for this feedback! I already use this method, 
I wanted to know if there was another way, to avoid having 20commit (or more) chained. :)

Comment: Hello! There are no universal solutions, but if you show your code, then most likely I will come up with a solution

Comment: One mutation can change anything, so you can create a new mutation to which you can transfer a lot of data and change everything that is required